# Как устроена плавающая запятая?

Tags: информатика

Вводится число в 10-ой системе счисления и переводится в форму с плавающей запятой дробь двоичной. Помогите разобраться на примере.
Пример:
Дано число в 10-ой **-12,56**, перевожу в 2-ую получаю **-1100,10001111**
Далее преобразую **-1,10010001111*10^3** Ведь так это делается? 
Я почему спрашиваю [здесь](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.A1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) например по другому делают и я не могу понять откуда берётся строчка выделенная красным.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]